# Are phenylboranes susceptible to ipso or meta substitution?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

Are phenylboranes susceptible to ipso or meta electrophilic aromatic substitution, i.e. what's the regioselectivity?

Answer (score 8):

A SciFinder search turns up very little on this type of transformation.

Qui and coworkers run halogenations of phenyl boronate esters using N-halosuccinimide using gold(III) catalysis. The regioselectivity was essentially 1:1:1 for ortho:meta:para. When the reaction was carried out with other substituents as well, the other substituent's directing group preference dominated the regioselectivity.
[Gold(III)-Catalyzed Halogenation of Aromatic Boronates with N-Halosuccinimides](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ol102350v)

There is one other reaction in SciFinder that is relevant, however I don't have access to the full text (and it's in Russian, so I wouldn't be able to read it anyway). The substrate is a benzene ring substituted with a borane cluster. The reported regioselectivity is 80:20 for meta:para.

Electrophilic substitution in the benzene ring of 9-phenyl-o- and -m-carborane. Zakharkin, L. I. et al *Zhurnal Organicheskoi Khimii*, 23(8), 1691-5; **1987**.

Comment: I think that it's somewhat strange that this isn't examined more thoroughly. I am also unsure whether a boronate ester can be compared to a borane. The carborane looks more appropriate for consideration (excluding the steric effect contribution which doesn't allow ortho). The meta-direction would be in agreement with the resonance withdrawal. Seems like there is no evidence on ipso substitution.

Comment: I don't think there's been a real need to investigate that type of reaction. Boron relatively rarely appears in the target compound of a synthesis. Even then, it is probably introduced late in the synthesis.

Comment: One other note, SciFinder reports that phenyl borane is typically prepared through the organo mercury compound, something many people probably don't want to do. As a reactant, phenyl borane has been oxidized to the phenol, used in hydroboration, and to make boron complexes.

Comment: Practically speaking yes, but theoretically speaking I think that it would be interesting to examine this topic, as boranyl is the only group that gives electrons by inductive effect and withdraws them by conjugation.

Answer (score 1):

9-(N-pyridine)-11-I-7,8-dicarba-nido-undecaborate are susceptible to ipso substitution and have substitution I-atom on Cl-atom. [Read](http://nasb.gov.by/eng/publications/vestich/vch09_4.php)

Rudakov D. A., Potkin V. I.
Chlorination of 9-dimethylsulfonio-7,8-dicarba-nido-undecaborane and 9-(N-pyridine-)-11-iodo-7,8-dicarba-nido-undecaborane. pp. 69--72

**Summary:**

Chlorination of 9-dimethylsulfonio-7,8-dicarba-nido-undecaborane and 11-iodo-9-(N-pyridine)-7,8-dicarba-nido-unde-caborane with chlorine in dichloromethane produces 6,11-dichloro-9-dimethylsulfonio-7,8-dicarba-nido-undecaborane and 11-chloro-6-iodo-9-(N-pyridine)-7,8-dicarba-nido-undecaborane in 20% and 44% yields, respectively.

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/259363537_Chlorination_of_9-dimethilsulfonio-78-dicarba-nido-undecaborane_and_9-N-pyridine-11-iodine-78-dicarba-nido-undecaborane